# Convergence Proof Isnt useful?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm just learning real analysis from Stephen Abbott's book, and one of the exercises is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}$$
I have come up with the following proof:
Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. For each $\epsilon$ choose $\mathcal{N}$ so that $\mathcal{N} > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$. This means for every $n \ge \mathcal{N}$, it follows:

$$n > \frac{2}{\epsilon} \mbox{ which is equivelant to } \frac{2}{n} < \epsilon$$
and thus:

$$
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
            \frac{2}{n} &= \frac{2}{n} \cdot \frac{n^2}{n^2} < \epsilon \\
            &\implies \frac{2n^2}{n^3} < \epsilon\\
            &\implies \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} < \epsilon\\
        \end{split}  
    \end{equation}
$$
Now at this point I could conclude
$$ \implies \left| \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 0 \right| < \epsilon $$
or
$$ \implies \left| \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 5 \right| < \epsilon $$
or
$$ \implies \left| \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 999 \right| < \epsilon $$
So there is no clear point of convergence, it could be $0$ or $5$ or $999$ or any number. What is wrong with this proof? Why can the number only be $0$ and not any other number? Please tell me.

Comment: Your post is unclear. Why can you conclude those additional other claims? Just because $x$ is arbitrarily small doesn't mean anything for $|x-L|$.

Comment: How do you conclude $\left| \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 5 \right| < \epsilon$ or $\left| \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 999 \right| < \epsilon$ from $\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} < \epsilon$ ???

Comment: For $\epsilon\le1$, you have $\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} < \epsilon\le1$.
Then $\left| \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 5 \right| \ge 5-1=4$, so the imply part doesn't hold

Comment: A remark: be careful with the $\Rightarrow$ on every line... For your proof, I would like an explanation for how you prove the claim right after "I could conclude blahblahblah or".

Comment: It looks like you could prove, in the same way, $\vert 0 - 0 \vert < 1$, but also $\vert 0 - 127 \vert < 1$.

Comment: @MartinR Because like if $|1|<\epsilon$ then $|1-45| < \epsilon$ and so on haha. I feel like there is something wrong but I cant put my finger on it....

Comment: @Plop but thats wrong :(

Comment: Yes! When you present a proof to someone, and the person says that he or she does not understand some point, it is your duty to give an argument or say "it's a hypothesis I'm making". So, try to give an argument for this part.

Comment: Do you know what $\vert a \vert$ means?

Comment: I think Plop has hit the nail on the head and you don't know what $\ \vert x \vert $ means. It means the absolute value of $x$, and is defined here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Real_numbers

Comment: @AdamRubinson I know what absolute value means- turn negative into positive and keep positive positive- but in terms of inequality, i can just take as much as I want from the limit and itll still be less than epsilon..

Comment: " absolute value means- turn negative into positive and keep positive positive" Exactly. So, for example, when $n=2,\ \left\lvert \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 999 \right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{8}{11} - 999 \right\rvert = \vert -998 \frac{3}{11} \vert = 998 \frac{3}{11}.$

Answer (score 2):

You can conclude
$$
\left| \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 0 \right| < \epsilon
$$
since
you have found
$$
\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} < \epsilon
$$
and
$$
\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} = \left| \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 0 \right|
.
$$

You can *not* conclude the others since
$$
\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} \neq \left| \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 5 \right|
$$
and
$$
\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} \neq \left| \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 999 \right|
.
$$

Comment: But it doesn't have to equal as long as its less than $\epsilon$?

Comment: And why do you claim that it is smaller than $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @fiftytwo. If what has to equal?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos. For big enough $n,$ that is. Or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @md2perpe Basically swap $\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}$ with $l$. Then if $|l|<0$ then so is $|l-400000|$. So like, why does it have to be $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of any other number

Comment: @fiftytwo. $|l|$ is never negative.